# Control video background from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I am working with a bootstrap template. I have organized my files in the root, and some php files in subfolders.

On my page [here](http://roulettesuite.com/personlighed.php) the video is working. This file is laying in the root

On my page [here](http://roulettesuite.com/kompetencer/kompetence-template.php) the video is not working. This file is laying in a subfolder

Question 1 : I cannot understand why the video is not playing in the subfolder?

Question 2 : I would like to control which videos there is played at specific sites. Fx:

site-1.php -> video 1

site-2.php -> video 2

site-3.php -> video 3

I have been searcing the javascript, there is controlling the videos. But cannot see any link to the video anywhere? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jevtzm02/)

I thought that the link to the video would be in the html, but there is no link to which video there should be displayed here.

```
<!-- banner start -->
            <!-- ================ -->
            <div class="banner video-background-banner pv-40 dark-translucent-bg hovered">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 text-center col-md-offset-2 pv-20">
                            <h2 class="title object-non-visible" data-animation-effect="fadeIn" data-effect-delay="100">About Us</h2>
                            <div class="separator object-non-visible mt-10" data-animation-effect="fadeIn" data-effect-delay="100"></div>
                            <p class="text-center object-non-visible" data-animation-effect="fadeIn" data-effect-delay="100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- banner end -->
```

**UPDATE**
**template.js**

```
//Video Background
        //-----------------------------------------------
        if($(".video-background").length>0) {
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                $(".video-background").vide({
                    mp4: "videos/background-video.mp4",
                    webm: "videos/background-video.webm",
                    poster: "videos/video-fallback.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 100%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            } else {
                $(".video-background").vide({
                    mp4: "videos/background-video.mp4",
                    webm: "videos/background-video.webm",
                    poster: "videos/video-poster.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 100%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            };

        };
        if($(".video-background-banner").length>0) {
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                $(".video-background-banner").vide({
                    mp4: "videos/background-video-banner.mp4",
                    webm: "videos/background-video-banner.webm",
                    poster: "videos/video-fallback.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 50%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            } else {
                $(".video-background-banner").vide({
                    mp4: "videos/background-video-banner.mp4",
                    webm: "videos/background-video-banner.webm",
                    poster: "videos/video-banner-poster.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 50%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            };
        };
```

That code is looking like this : [Example](http://roulettesuite.com/personlighed.php)

---

I tried to add this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner video-background-banner-test pv-40 dark-translucent-bg hovered">
```

**JS**

```
if($(".video-background-banner-test").length>0) {
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                $(".video-background-banner-test").vide({
                    mp4: "videos/background-video-banner.mp4",
                    webm: "videos/background-video-banner.webm",
                    poster: "videos/video-fallback.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 50%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            } else {
                $(".video-background-banner-test").vide({
                    mp4: "../videos/background-video-banner.mp4",
                    webm: "../videos/background-video-banner.webm",
                    poster: "../videos/video-banner-poster.jpg"
                }, {
                    volume: 1,
                    playbackRate: 1,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    position: "50% 50%", // Similar to the CSS `background-position` property.
                    posterType: "jpg", // Poster image type. "detect" — auto-detection; "none" — no poster; "jpg", "png", "gif",... - extensions.
                    resizing: true
                });
            };
        };
```

The video is played but there is a class there is not called? because the height is different: [Example](http://roulettesuite.com/kompetencer/kompetence-template.php)

Comment: in the sub folder file, are you doing `../` to get out of the subfolder? (for the src)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You mean on the js link? `<script src="/plugins/vide/jquery.vide.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, like `" ../videos/yourvideo.mp4"`

Comment: Should I post as an answer?

Comment: Yes please. I cannot find that line of code `" ../videos/yourvideo.mp4"`

Comment: What I mean, is, that you have a `<video>`tag right, with a `src`?

Comment: look at this https://codepen.io/MostafaFathey/pen/qxbAo/ , well you see the `src`? give provide an image of how your whole website files are organised

Comment: But there is no `<video>` in my html that I posted in my question. That is the html code. Where did you see the video tag? On the inspect of my site?

Comment: no no, I mean  that usually, videos use the `<video>` tag

Comment: Ah okay thank you. But just for learning purpose. If I had to keep it how I had now. Is there any solution on my question then?

Comment: I have no clue, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template uses a plugin called [Vide](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide) for the video backgrounds.
So you would look for either a `data-vide-bg` attribute or a line like `$('selector').vide(options)` which I found in `template.js` (line 1340 and following). That's where the paths are defined.

If you have control over that file, i.e. if you can edit it, you could add logic there to use different paths for your sub pages.

If you can't edit that file, you will need to destroy the previous Vide instance and create your own:

```
$('.video-background').data('vide').destroy();
$('.video-background').vide(pathOptions, playerOptions);
```

See [here](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#instructions) what `pathOptions` and `playerOptions` are.

Comment: Thank you a lot for that. It is correct what you are saying, the js code for the background video is in template.js. If you have time I just updated my question. I am a little bit in doubt how I can add different videos? Should I make a new if/else statement everytime? In my updated question I gave an example.

Comment: Ah found out. In the layout.css the `class .banner.video-background-banner`is called. So if I add the css with a new video `.test {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}` it is working